# Excel - Does a range of cells contain a value in a list?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to answer - does a range of cells (A1:E1) contain any value from a list (G1:G50)

In other words: Does A1 OR B1 OR C1 OR D1 OR E1 contain any value that appears in G1:G50

Answer (score 0):

This formula might give you the result you want:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(MATCH(A1:E1,G1:G50,0),0))>0
```

You have to make it an array formula. That means after typing or pasting this formula into you target cell you have to commit it not as usual with simple 'Return' but by 'Ctrl+Shift+Return'. If you did it right the formula will be surrounded by curled brackets in formula bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNTIF` within `SUMPRODUCT` like this

`=SUMPRODUCT(0+(COUNTIF(A1:E1,G1:G50)>0))>0`

That doesn't need "array entry"